# Rails 3.0 required javascript libraries for method delete

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I was wondering what are the specific javascript libraries required to get the method => delete to work. Also, I'm having problems because I want to use the jquery library, and if I include :defaults it doesn't work. Is there a way to integrate the two?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can run in Rails if you include the UJS script. Your best option is to use the following:

https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails